# docker-compose - failed to mount local volume: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean

This works on my local ubuntu machine, but when I try to on my digitalocean droplet it fails. I'm wondering if it's a permissions issue but not sure. The folder is definitely there, although it's empty when creating the containers because I haven't run the `yarn build` command at that point.

**The error:**

```
Attaching to client, db, server, webserver
Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/app_web-root/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount ./client/build/:/var/lib/docker/volumes/app_web-root/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory
```

**Base app directory:**

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me 1215 Jul 22 02:15 README.md
drwxrwxr-x  6 me me 4096 Jul 22 16:50 client
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me 1447 Jul 22 17:14 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root   4096 Jul 22 16:37 nginx-conf
drwxrwxr-x 10 me me 4096 Jul 22 16:37
```

**Code:**

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database_development
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE
    networks:
      - app-network
  client:
    container_name: client
    build: ./client
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    networks:
      - app-network
  server:
    container_name: server
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 4242:4242
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - web-root:/build
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - app-network
  webserver:
    image: nginx:mainline-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - web-root:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      #- certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      #- certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - server
    networks:
      - app-network
volumes:
  web-root:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: ./client/build
      o: bind
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

`ls -l client`:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me    228 Jul 22 02:15 Dockerfile
drwxrwxr-x 2 me me   4096 Jul 22 16:50 build
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me    602 Jul 22 02:15 craco.config.js
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root     4096 Jul 22 02:20 node_modules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     2035 Jul 22 16:37 package.json
drwxrwxr-x 3 me me   4096 Jul 22 02:15 public
drwxrwxr-x 5 me me   4096 Jul 22 02:15 src
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   488599 Jul 22 16:37 yarn.lock
```

EDIT:

Fixed it by skipping first copying to a local volume then to another container and just have them all share the same volume like:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database_development
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE
    networks:
      - app-network
  client:
    container_name: client
    build: ./client
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
      - web-root:/build
      - /app/node_modules
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    networks:
      - app-network
  server:
    container_name: server
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 4242:4242
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - web-root:/build
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - app-network
  webserver:
    image: nginx:mainline-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - web-root:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      #- certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      #- certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - server
    networks:
      - app-network
volumes:
  web-root:
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Does the folder you are mounting to exist on the droplet?

Comment: `/var/lib/docker/volumes/app_web-root/_data`? Yes that folder exists on the droplet.

Comment: The way you are organizing your volumes is really confusing. Are you trying to share volumes between your services? Why does your `server` service need your "./client/build"? The `type: none` and `o: bind` options of your `web-root` volume definition are strange too if you're just trying to create a simple bind mount.

Comment: I'll admit I don't know  **** about Docker, so I appreciate your help and patience. My understanding is that the `server` will need to be serving the files in `client/build` the way that `webpack-dev-server` has been doing in my development environment. The `type: none` and `o: bind` are straight from this digitalocean guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-a-containerized-node-js-application-with-nginx-let-s-encrypt-and-docker-compose

Comment: im stuck at the same step, did you find anything?